# Can someone please explain this regex to me?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I just want to understand this regex better:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
```

I understand the rewrite and _REQUEST.  I just want to understand the regex better.

From this, I assume that the backslash before the % sign means that it will allow %.  Is it also allowing pipes and brackets?

What is the purpose of allowing a percentage sign?  Doesn't that just open up the possibility of an attack with hexadecimal characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the highest level, the regular expression can be broken down into 3 parts, separated by the '|' character which means logical OR. 
Part 1: `=`
Part 2: `\[`
Part 3: `\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}`

A string matching any one of these subexpression will match the whole expression.

Part 1 simply means if the string is composed of one character, which is the equals character: `=`.

Part 2 means that the string is composed of one character, which is the left bracket character: `[`. The backslash is there to escape the left square bracket character, which has a special meaning in regular expressions (see part 3)

Part 3 is composed of two parts. First, `\%` which indicates that for a string to match this expression it must begin with the percent '%' character. The backslash is there to escape it since it also has a special meaning in regular expressions. the next segment, `[0-9A-Z]` means that the following character can be composed of a either a character between 0 and 9, or a character between A-Z. Either one should work fine. The last segment `{0,2}` modifies the previous segment, and says that between 0 and 2 characters as specified in the previous segment are acceptable. So all the following strings match part 3:

```
%
%A
%B
%0
%3
%AF
%1G
%8M
```

the following strings do not match part 3:

```
'' (the empty string)
1A (doesn't start with %)
%3f (lowercase f is not allowed)
%F5A (3 characters following the percent sign)
```

I find it helpful to use an online tool to help construct/decipher regular expressions such as: http://rubular.com/

Comment: Actually, the pattern has no `$` end of string anchor so the regex is not imposing any restrictions on characters following the `%12`. Thus, the `%F5A` (or `%F5ABCDEF`) actually would result in a succssful match.

Answer (score 2):

The part in  parentheses says:

An equal sign **or** a left square bracket **or** a percent sign followed by any number or capital letter occurring 0 to 2 times.

I have no idea what the purpose of it is.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I wanted to not allow the percentage, would I do this?
(=|\[[0-9A-Z]{0,2})  or do I need that additional pipe?

Comment: You would still need the second pipe if you want 3 different possibilities. Also you need to escape the square bracket